# Remove two chains by a string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace these two strings to "remove":

> example: test
>
> example 2 : test 2

My code:

```
String myString= in.nextLine();
myString= myString.replaceAll("example: OR example 2 :", "remove");
```

The idea is to eliminate example: or example 2 : to "remove" regardless of which one I find, so the final resul will be:

> remove
>
> remove

For my code, it is important that the elimination be in the same "replaceAll" hence the use of the operator or.

Comment: `example: OR example 2 :` isn't a valid regex (I think you need to grab a regex tutorial). Try something like `(example|example 2):.*`  instead (whether this works depends on what your input actually looks like but `.*` shouldn't go multiline by default so it should be ok).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done either

```
replaceAll("(?:example|example 2 ):.*", "remove")
```

or

```
replaceAll("example(?: 2 )?:.*", "remove")
```